# What is the best way to align links with icons in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know what is the best possible way to align links with icon images with a vertical navigation.

So far my code looks like this:

```
<li><img src="./images/icon1.png"><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li> 
<li><img src="./images/icon2.png"><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
<li><img src="./images/icon3.png"><a href="link3.html">Link 3</a></li>
<li><img src="./images/icon4.png"><a href="link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
```

Currently, obviously they are not aligned how I need them. The links need to be aligned to the middle of the icon images. What is the best way to do this? Using CSS if necessary.

Comment: There is no 'best' way. It all depends on the situation. For this, however, I would do it by creating one PNG file (a sprite) then position it as a background within the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something that will require multiple images, I recommend using a sprite sheet which will contain all your images (one large .png file which also reduces the number of images loaded on the page). Assign each `<a>` a background image in your CSS.

HTML:

```
<li><a href="link1.html" class="link1">Link 1</a></li> 
<li><a href="link2.html" class="link2">Link 1</a></li> 
<li><a href="link3.html" class="link3">Link 1</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
li a.link1 {
    background: url(/images/spritesheet.png) no-repeat 10px 25px; /* 10px is the value of the horizontal position of the image; 25px is the value of the vertical position */
    width: 15px; /* the width of the image */
    height: 15px; /* the height of the image */
    padding: 0 8px; /* enough padding to account for the width of the image */
}
```

[SpriteCow.com](http://spritecow.com) is a great resource for getting the exact position of the image on the sprite sheet.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to make the icon a background image that sits in the padding for the link, but this means the link urls are hard-coded into your css:

markup:

```
<li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
```

css

```
a {
  padding-left: 20px; /* or really whatever size you need for your icon */
  background: url(./images/icon1.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: So before I would do this, create one image of all of the icon images?